# Bundle unable to install babel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im starting a new project using rails 4.2, ruby 2.3.0.
When I use bundle install I get an error:

> Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/babel-source-5.8.35/lib/babel.js
>   An error occurred while installing babel-source (5.8.35), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install babel-source -v '5.8.35'` succeeds before bundling.

Running

```
gem install babel-source -v '5.8.35'
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/babel-source-5.8.35/lib/babel.js

I checked out the permissions on the file in question but that doesn't change anything.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: It does look like a permissions problem. Are you sure everything in `.rvm` is writable by your user?

Comment: Whats the quick way to do that?

Comment: ls -l would show you who's the owner of the file and the permissions.

Comment: Ive changed the permissions on the files in the directory and the directory itself.  I still cannot access the file.  If I drop the file into terminal, it simply says access denied, even with sudo

Comment: Usually `sudo chown -R matt ~/.rvm` should do it.